# multithread REST API Call

Tags: c#, multithreading, rest, api

I'm working with a REST call which uses paging on the request, so the initial request will be page 1/40. Processing 40 requests to recieve a page at a time takes a bit of time, I'm wondering whats the best practice to implement some multithreading?

I can collate all of my result sets into individual DataTable and then merge them together at the end, but before I start down that path I was wondering what peoples thoughts are?

My project is C# and works perfectly retrieving all pages on the results, but I'm wondering if i can do this faster?
[image]

Comment: You could get number of pages in advance and then run multiple threads to get single pages and finally merge results. But keep in mind that this couldn't be allowed from source website, so before walking this way check their policy.

Comment: The number of total pages is provided with the first call, I've checked the documentation and they allow 100 requsts in a 15 second period, so I think this is ok. the total execution time for 40 pages (40 requests) is about 38 seconds - lets just say 1 second per request/page

Answer (score 0):

What are these "pages"? 
You can collect all to a concurrent data structure of some sort.
Each call can be async, then await all responses and concatenate the responses as you require.

Comment: The pages are sets of Data in JSON format which I then serialise into set of DataTable objects for further processing. The initial request defaults to Page1 and the response contains the total pages.

Comment: Then best I can think of is collect them async and if reordering is heavy simply add them whenever the next required part received.
Perhaps others will have better suggestion here.